I am unable to properly delete an Azurite table. When I recreate it the original table comes back
I am writing a web application and one of the things it does it to create and populate Azurite tables. I can view these tables in Azurite Storage Explorer.
However, if I:

Delete a table (in Azurite Storage Explorer) that has data
Recreate that table

Then the table gets recreated, with no data, but with all the original columns.
For comparison, if I create a table that I've never created before, I just get PartitionKey and RowKey, which is what I would expect.
This happens even if I create and populate the table in code. This is becoming a real problem, since the process of development has caused me to remove columns and rename columns, etc. But when I view my tables in Azurite, all those old columns are still there. There just now populated by null.
Is there a way of resolving this, other than resetting, or doing something else that would involve a whole lot of extra work? Am I missing something?

The issue likely involves retaining original columns in an Azurite table despite deletion and recreation, potentially due to metadata not reloading. Solutions include restarting the active HMaster from Ambari UI or deleting orphan blob files using HDFS commands.

This issue is likely caused by how Azurite handles table metadata, particularly with columns (properties) from previously deleted tables being "remembered" even when you recreate them.

I'm not sure how either of these comments relate to my issue, other than simply restating my problem. How do I resolve the issue? And what on earth has Ambari got to do with anything?
